# SQL - confused with aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregate

I currently have this query:

```
select
  customers.emailaddress,
  MAX(orders.orderdate) as "last order"
from orders
join customers
  on orders.customerID = customers.customerID
group by customers.emailaddress
```

Which gives me the emails, and the last order date. With the 'Orders' table, there is a field named 'PaymentTotal', how can I get this based on the value returned by MAX(orders.orderdate)? (ie am trying to get the amount of the last order per email)

Comment: it would be useful to know which SQL server you are talking about. PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc...

Comment: I think it is MS-SQL, its packaged with a shoppingcart we use that is ASP(.net) based (hence my assumption it's MS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c.EmailAddress, om.MaxOrderDate, o.PaymentTotal
from (
    select CustomerID, MAX(orders.orderdate) as MaxOrderDate
    from orders 
    group by CustomerID
) om
inner join orders o on om.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    and om.MaxOrderDate = o.orderdate
inner join customers c on o.customerID = c.customerID
```

Comment: I'm hoping the orderdate must be unique per customer otherwise this will not return the expected results. I wonder what the orderdate column's type is...

Comment: Orderdate is datetime. Thanks for all the help. So can someone breakdown what happened with the query above? I would really like to learn so I can do this on my own next time :)

Comment: the sub query "om" finds the customer id and date, then it joins the order and customer table back on that value to retrive the customer and total for that order.